# How to get rounded Corner button image in QML after tiling

Tags: qml

I have Button image with Rounded Button image. I am tiling image to get bigger button in QML . I am using parent as rectangle and image as BorderImage. After tiling I am getting rectangle on top image is visible. I need to remove the part of the rectangle so that only rounded button image (Has transparency) is Visible. Even i need to change the color of the behind rectangle so that Color animation is possible.

Please suggest efficient method to remove the behind rectangle and provide the color animation also.

I am attaching the Rounded button border image as attachment and source code for tiling the button image.

```
Rectangle{
id:outerBorderRect
smooth:true
anchors.fill:parent
//opacity:.25
//border.width:0
BorderImage{

id:innerBorderRect
smooth:true
anchors.fill:parent
border{left:20;top:16;right:17;bottom:20}
horizontalTileMode:BorderImage.Round
verticalTileMode:BorderImage.Round

source:"button_3.png"

}
}
```

Comment: This is the well-known problem of missing masking, that I think persists into Qt Quick 2. The only solution I've encountered so far is to write your own QML component in C++ and then use that.

Answer (score 0):

A simple and semi-hack way to do this is to use the `radius` property in `Rectangle` to hide the corners of your button.

Or you could use a proper mask by using Qt's [OpacityMask](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgraphicaleffects/qml-qtgraphicaleffects1-opacitymask.html).

I'm not sure what kind of animation you're looking for. You'll have to provide more details for me to answer that part.